# Something wrong when deleting an element in a Binary search tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I only use function `insert`, `remove` and `midorder`.

```
#include<iostream>

template<class Elem>
class BinNode
{
public:
    virtual Elem& getVal() = 0;
};

template<class Elem>
class BinNodePtr:public BinNode<Elem>
{
public:
    Elem val;
    BinNodePtr* lc;
    BinNodePtr* rc;
    BinNodePtr()
    {
        lc = rc = NULL;
    }
    ~BinNodePtr()
    {
        delete lc;
        delete rc;
    }
    Elem& getVal()
    {
        return this->val;
    }
};

template<class Elem>
class BST
{
public:
    BinNodePtr<Elem> *root;
    int nodenum;
    void midorder(BinNodePtr<Elem>* start);
public:
    BST()
    {
        root = NULL;
        nodenum = 0;
    }
    bool insert(BinNodePtr<Elem>*&ptr,const Elem &e);//
    void remove(BinNodePtr<Elem>*&start,const Elem &e);//
    BinNodePtr<Elem>* getRoot(){return root;}
};

template<class Elem>
void BST<Elem>::midorder(BinNodePtr<Elem> *start)
{
    if(start == NULL) return;
    midorder(start->lc);
    printf("%d ",start->getVal());
    midorder(start->rc);
}

template<class Elem>
bool BST<Elem>::insert(BinNodePtr<Elem>*&ptr,const Elem &e)
{
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        ptr = new BinNodePtr<Elem>;
        ptr->lc = NULL;
        ptr->rc = NULL;
        ptr->val = e;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(ptr->val < e || ptr->val == e)
        {
            insert(ptr->rc,e);
        }
        else
        {
            insert(ptr->lc,e);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template<class Elem>
void BST<Elem>::remove(BinNodePtr<Elem>*&start,const Elem &e)
{
    if(start == NULL)
        return ;
    if(start->val < e)
        remove(start->rc,e);
    else if(start->val > e)
        remove(start->lc,e);
    else
    {
        if(start->lc == NULL && start->rc == NULL)
        {
            delete start;
        }
        else if(start->lc == NULL)
        {
            BinNodePtr<Elem> *temp = start;
            start = start->rc;
            delete (temp);
        }
        else if(start->rc == NULL)
        {
            BinNodePtr<Elem> *temp = start;
            start = start->lc;
            delete temp;
        }
        else
        {
            BinNodePtr<Elem>* temp = start->rc;
            while(temp->lc!= NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->lc;
            }
            start->val = temp->val;
            remove(start->rc,temp->val);
        }

    }
}
int main()
{
    BST<int> myBST;
    (myBST.insert(myBST.root,10));
    (myBST.insert(myBST.root,20));
    (myBST.insert(myBST.root,5));
    (myBST.insert(myBST.root,30));
    myBST.midorder(myBST.getRoot());
    myBST.remove(myBST.root,10);
    myBST.midorder(myBST.getRoot());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have successfully inserted 10, 20, 5, 30 because I can `"printf"` them out, but the program breaks down when I use function `remove`. I debugged this and found that there is something wrong in function `remove` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I had a quick look. If you step though the `remove` function, you will notice that you actually delete the node conatining `20` instead of the node containing `10`.

Comment: But I have covered  the node containing 10 with 20,so I can delete the node containing with 20.

Comment: One problem I see is that you are not resetting 'start' in case "if(start->lc == NULL && start->rc == NULL)" making it a dangling pointer

Comment: If you debugged it, you should be able to be more specific than "there is something wrong". Which line gives a problem? Have you evaluated all the applicable variables and traced them back to where they were initialized to see that all of them were set up correctly?

Comment: In insert looks ok except you should return insert(...), instead of return false at end. Function remove contains multiple mistake of leaving pointers dangling, better you should write on paper what you want to do and then reimplement.